Suspend quit working
After I installed Ubuntu 22.04, Suspend worked properly for about 18 months. Then Suspend started taking a few seconds before the computer went dark, then suspend quit altogether. I'm not aware of having done anything to cause that behavior.
Ideas welcome.

You say "suspend quit altogether" but explain exactly what you mean - does a suspend do absolutely nothing? Or does it do something but not actually suspend? Look at your system logs before/during/after you attempt to suspend e.g. tail -f /var/log/syslog or run sudo dmesg -w in a terminal then try a suspend. Update your original question with any more info or any suspect messages/errors
